# Security implications for setting document.domain in iframed content

Tags: security, cookies, cross-domain

I have two sub domains `content` and `www` under the domain `example.com`. Content from `content.example.com` is being presented in `www.example.com` via an iframe.

Because the content on `content.example.com` needs to communicate to `www.example.com` I've set `document.domain="example.com"` and also set `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` on the iframe.

I'm concerned that if users can upload the content to be displayed in the iframe it could be exploitable, i.e., send the content of the cookies to a remote domain to hijack the session or other security exploits.

I've setup another domain, `www.example2.com` and put an AJAX request in the iframed content at `content.example.com` to test my theory and am sending `document.cookie` to the remote domain. This results in the `_ga` cookies being sent to the remote domain. I've allowed `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')` on the remote domain so it doesn't cause any issues.

Why are only the _ga cookies being sent? I have a number of other cookies in there on the same domain and path as the _ga cookies yet they aren't sent. Are there other security risks in doing this? Ideally I'd like it only possible for communication between `content.example.com` and `www.example.com` and it looks like it's mostly doing this, except for Google Analytics cookies, which will mean that others might be able to do it too.

Comment: _I have two domains, `content.example.com` and `www.example.com`_ `content.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`

Comment: yeah sorry, I have two sub domains.

Comment: to access a domain cookie from a subdomain, you don't have to go too heavy. It is easy task

Comment: *.domain.com or set path '/'

Comment: I'm accessing it fine, its more so the security implications around sending secure data from one domain to another outside example.com. _ga is being sent, but nothing else. Could an attacker get that something else? Why is _ga special? I couldn't see anything in the values of the _ga cookies that would permit it being sent to an external domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONP to communicate different domains, regardless of cross-domain settings and policies.

However JSONP requires the server side to build the callback function with the returned data as a parameter.

I would suggest to load plain Javascript content from the server, which has the same cross-domain independence and security as a JSON request.

Say you have a Javascript file, `data.js`, in `content.example.com`, or a service returning the same content as the file in the response,
with a JSON object, prefixed with a variable assignment:

```
result = {
  "string1": "text1",
  "object1": {
    "string2": "text2",
    "number1": 5.6
  },
  "number2": 7,
  "array1": ["text3", "text4"]
}
```

Then, in your web page, in `www.example.com`, you can have a script with function `loadJS`,
which loads the server response as a script:

```
var loadJS = function (url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = url;
  script.onload = function (ev) {
    callback(window.result);
    delete window.result;
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  };
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};

window.onload = function () {
  loadJS('http://content.example.com/data.js', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Same function can be used in `content.example.com` for requests in the opposite direction.

In order to set cookies or perform any other functionality available in JS,
the response script, `data.js`, may contain a function rather than a JSON object:

```
result = (function () {
  document.cookie = "cookie1=Value1; cookie2=Value2;";
  return true;
})();
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost with your answer. The attacker won't be able to control the content in the parent of the iframe so won't be able add javascript to it (loadJS). From my previous use of JSONP, it is still bound to the same rules as a standard AJAX request as far as access to cookies is concerned however it can help with the server communication where you might not have full control of the server and your getting cross site scripting preventions because the header response won't allow it. Is that right?

Comment: Not JSONP nor JS are bound to the same rules as AJAX. You can load a JSON object with AJAX, but you will have the cross-domain problem, and, more importantly, in terms of security, the received content is visible in the destination document, whereas JSONP and JS, loaded as scripts, are sandboxed, i.e. executed but not readable, reason why they are not subject to the cross-domain restriction.

Comment: Anyway, this is just a suggestion to achieve secure cross-domain communication in the simplest way. More elaborated solutions will require strong client-server encryption techniques.